# Magento1.9 - Selected option with explode array exception

Tags: magento-1.9, database, custom

We're having an issue with getting a selected option from our database. It's a custom made plugin, but it contains a few option values, like these:

```
array(
   'value' => 17529,
   'label' => Mage::helper('storelocator')->__('Qwic'),
),
array(
   'value' => 18789,
   'label' => Mage::helper('storelocator')->__('Victoria'),
),
array(
   'value' => ('17500,17156,17154,17446,17300,17379,17400,17394,17387,17392,17377,17436,17167,21353,17513,17184,21352,17386,17401,17456,20335,17186,17370,17417,17390,17511,17367,17366,17373,17393,17422,17389,17188,17388,17358,17357,17415,19548'),
                'label' => Mage::helper('storelocator')->__('Andere merken'),   ),
```

But now, the bottom option value never stays selected after saving, because the values are being exploded when got from database, like this:

```
$manuArr = explode(',',$storePU->getManufacture());
```

How can I make sure the final value is selected? So, make an exception or something in the explode part? I'm not a Magento expert, so I have no clue how to fix this.

Comment: Do you want to select last SKU "19548"  to be selected?

Comment: The whole final option should be selected, which has all those numbers/SKU's. Is there any possibility to do that, or do they really need to be all seperate?

Comment: did the database stores all those values?you have problem in getting those value?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the thing. They do get stored in the database. The problem is that when opening the page again, the option isn't selected anymore, because PHP explodes it with , (I guess), so it tries to find all the SKU's seperately.

Comment: is it multiselect field ?

Comment: Yes, it's a multiselect field.

Comment: try referring this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/75242/populating-the-multiselect-field-with-available-values-pre-selected-in-admin-for

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I tried the solution of your link, but it didn't work. Also, I can type any value ('value' => 17529 or 'value' => all numbers here) I want, yet it's not being selected.